# how to get fixed static images url for jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I generated the html webpage in jenkins jobs and try to success/failure icons inside.

But I noticed it is linked to the url with some random number `9b17c509` in the path

https://ci.jenkins.io/static/9b17c509/images/32x32/red.png

What I preferred is the fixed url for every jenkins instance like

https://ci.jenkins.io/static/images/32x32/blue.png

Any suggestion to solve it ?

BTW: I don't want to connect to external web for those images

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I checked several links and got the answer below ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`9b17c509` looks like a cache.

We can use `/images/32x32/blue.png`

see https://ci.jenkins.io/images/32x32/blue.png

Comment: Is there a green one somewhere for those that prefer that color?

Answer (score 0):

For a `hudson.model.Result` or the result name like "SUCCESS" you can get a ball icon with `hudson.model.BallColor` .

In Groovy

```
  def iconUrl = (result as BallColor).getImageOf("16x16")
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I get a  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant hudson.model.BallColor.SUCCESS`